# How can I join this two array in Swift

Tags: swift

```
{
    "couriers" : [
      {
        "id" : 30,
        "name" : "abc"
      }
    ],
    "new_couriers" : [
      {
        "name_display" : "abc",
        "fee" : "1.00",
        "name" : "ABC Express"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to join this two array together and display in UITableView, not sure is it possible to append it.

```
    struct AllCourier {
        var couriers = [Couriers]()
        var new_couriers = [NewCouriers]() 
    }

    for item in allCourier {
        available_courier.new_couriers = item.new_courier
        available_courier.couriers =  item.couriers
    }
```

I created a struct and add class into it

```
    func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
        return allCourier.count
    }

    // create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingOptionCell
        let item = allCourier[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I had edited the post not sure are you able to help or give a suggestion to resolve the issue. thank you very much

Comment: What two dictionaries, I see two arrays containing different types but no dictionaries?

Comment: You posted data that appears to be a dump of an already-combined dictionary. You also showed a struct that appears to contain arrays of other structs, not dictionaries. Where is the definition of the dictionaries that you want to combine?

Comment: Also note that dictionaries are a terrible way to store the model for a table view, since they are an unordered collection. A table view needs to have it's model kept in a stable order. You really want to use an array, or an array of arrays, as the data model for a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to creatively think of a way to do this.
You cannot simply concatenate two arrays which hold different object classes.

### Hint:

```swift
class BaseCourier {
    ...
}

class Courier: BaseCourier {
    ...
}

class NewCourier: BaseCourier {
    ...
}

let couriers = [Courier()]
let newCouriers = [NewCourier()]

let allCouriers = couriers + newCouriers
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre, how can I join let allCouriers = couriers + newCouriers together yea?

Comment: `+` operand joins the 2 arrays if they both hold the same Object Class.
It'll only work if you extend `BaseCourier` in both `Courier` & `NewCourier` classes.